# How to implement a BOUNDED source for Flink's batch execution mode?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-flink

I'm trying to do a Flink (1.12.1) batch job, with the following steps:

- Custom SourceFunction to connect with MongoDB
- Do any flatmaps and maps to transform some data
- Sink it in other MongoDB

I'm trying to run it in a StreamExecutionEnvironment , with RuntimeExexutionMode.BATCH, but the application throws a exception because detect my source as UNBOUNDED... And I can't set it BOUNDED ( it must finish after collect all documents in the mongo collection )

The exception:

```
    exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected an UNBOUNDED source with the 'execution.runtime-mode' set to 'BATCH'. This combination is not allowed, please set the 'execution.runtime-mode' to STREAMING or AUTOMATIC
        at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:193)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.shouldExecuteInBatchMode(StreamGraphGenerator.java:335)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.generate(StreamGraphGenerator.java:258)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1958)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1943)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1782)
        at com.grupotsk.bigdata.matadatapmexporter.MetadataPMExporter.main(MetadataPMExporter.java:33)
```

Some code:

Execution environment

```
public static StreamExecutionEnvironment getBatch() {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);
    
    env.addSource(new MongoSource()).print();
    
    return env;
    
}
```

Mongo source:

```
public class MongoSource extends RichSourceFunction<Document> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8321722349907219802L;
    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private MongoCollection mc;
    
    
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration con) {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/database"));
        
        mc=mongoClient.getDatabase("database").getCollection("collection");
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Document> ctx) throws Exception {
        
        MongoCursor<Document> itr=mc.find(Document.class).cursor();
        while(itr.hasNext())
            ctx.collect(itr.next());
        this.cancel();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        mongoClient.close();
        
    }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sources used with `RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH` must implement `Source` rather than `SourceFunction`. And the sink should implement `Sink` rather than `SinkFunction`.

See [Integrating Flink into your ecosystem - How to build a Flink connector from scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCMfbGv38u8)  for an introduction to these new interfaces. They are described in [FLIP-27: Refactor Source Interface](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/co_zBQ) and [FLIP-143: Unified Sink API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/KEJ4CQ).